# Is there a way to intercept requests made by devices connected to wifi hotspot at the application layer?

Tags: android, vpn, mac-address

Android has a wifi hotspot feature which lets other devices connect to it, and use its internet connection to access the internet.

Without rooting or modifying the OS, is there an API that can be accessed to intercept requests from a particular MAC address connected to it (at the application layer) ?

For example, similar to a VPN - but MAC address specific ? If someone can point me where to get started I can do the research myself, but this is too deep into android internals, that I think someone with experience making a VPN may be able to easily answer.